# Pagination in Jquery Datatable in asp.net webforms

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, datatables, webforms

I have an API, which accepts page number and page size as a parameter to return user details.
Loading data to the jquery data table. Needs to pass page number and size to API for fetch the data each time. How can I get and pass the page number to webmethod and enable next button all time. Because when i loaded first time data it only shows page number as 1 and Next button is disabled.

```
 var tableUserDetails = $("#grdUser").DataTable({
    processing: true,
    filter: true,
    orderMulti: false,
    paging: true,
    searching: true,
    bFilter: true,
    bsort: true,
    bInfo: true,
    pagingType: "simple",
    columns: [{ "data": "Id" },
    { "data": "Name" },
    { "data": "userName" },
    { "data": "email" },
    { "data": "role" }
    ]
});

function getUsers() {
    var info =tableUserDetails.page.info();
    $.ajax({
        data: '{pageNumber:' + info.page+1 + ', pageSize:' + 10 + '}',
        type: "POST",
        url: "MyPage.aspx/GetUsers",
        contentType: Constants.ContentType,
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            debugger;
            alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
        },
        success: function (result) {
            
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Using a gridview/listview and code behind would be so much less work. With all those calls you not saving bandwidth or getting more speed. And if you drop the whole gridview inside of a update panel, then you have partial post-backs anyway. And thus you can have a datatable drive the grid, and toss in a data-view, which allows sorting and filtering, and of course such objects (gridview/listview) also support data pager out of the box. If you use your own jQuery grid, then you code quite much all of the above features that are built in and all that work don't result in better performance anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for this: [DataTables server side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side). The configuration you have is not loading partially the data. It assumes you have all the rows when you set the dataset.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php"
    } );
} );
```

And the format of the returned data should be like this:

```
{
  "draw": 3,
  "recordsTotal": 57,
  "recordsFiltered": 57,
  "data": [
    [
      "Airi",
      "Satou",
      "Accountant",
      "Tokyo",
      "28th Nov 08",
      "$162,700"
    ],
    /* etc */
```

An example of C# like response:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Resultset to be JSON stringified and set back to client.
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    [SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "InconsistentNaming")]
    public class DataTableResultSet
    {
        /// <summary>Array of records. Each element of the array is itself an array of columns</summary>
        public List<List<string>> data = new List<List<string>>();

        /// <summary>value of draw parameter sent by client</summary>
        public int draw;

        /// <summary>filtered record count</summary>
        public int recordsFiltered;

        /// <summary>total record count in resultset</summary>
        public int recordsTotal;

        public string ToJSON()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }
    }
```

#### Edit - How to post with ajax

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mytable').DataTable({
      processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
      ajax: {
        data: '{pageNumber:' + info.page+1 + ', pageSize:' + 10 + '}',
        type: "POST",
        url: "MyPage.aspx/GetUsers",
        contentType: Constants.ContentType,
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            debugger;
            alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
        },
        success: function (result) {
            
        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: API only returns the data based on the page number which we provide. So how can i implement this? like ../getuser/{pagenumber}/{pagesize} and returns total number of rows and the data based on the pagesize

Comment: Check the update for more information, if you want to post data instead.